# Mapbox dependency in Android studio Bumblebee

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, mapbox-android, android-studio-bumblebee

So as it mentioned in [mapbox installation guide](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/guides/install/), in order to add dependency to top level gradle, this is what should be done:

[image: click here to see the image].

But as you see in the picture it failed to build the gradle and it gives me that error. The structure of project level gradle is also changed to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5V9xq.png) in **Android Studio Bumblebee**.

How should I add Mapbox dependencies to my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mapbox dependency should be added into settings.gradle file.

It can be seen [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/guides/install/#add-the-dependency).

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()

        //For Mapbox
        maven {
            url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven'
            authentication {
                basic(BasicAuthentication)
            }
            credentials {
                // Do not change the username below.
                // This should always be `mapbox` (not your username).
                username = 'mapbox'
                // Use the secret token you stored in gradle.properties as the password
                password = "<your secret api key>"
            }

        }
    }
}
```